# Extract specific text from a div with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a webpage with BS4 and Python 3.5. 
Trying to extract only the username (linked text) from a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="about"><a href="es_viewprofile.aspx?profile_id=110181766">claudiakenzo</a>&nbsp;33&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pasar el rato&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="green">En línea</font></div>
```

Mi goal is to get ONLY the FIRST part of the div, in this case, the string "claudiakenzo"

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
            for link in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'about'}):
            print(username = link.text)
```

Theoretically I should be getting what I want, but no...I am getting as output:

```
claudiakenzo 33    Pasar el rato   En línea
```

I don´t want the "33", "Pasar el rato" or "En línea" parts of it.
What am I doing wrong and what´s the right code to extract what I need?
Unfortunately some usernames also contain numbers, so using re is complicated...but I sense there must be a simpler way to do this than using re.

PS- If there´s an easier solution to the problem with Selenium, I am willing to try that too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take some time reading BS4 docs. In the meanwhile this should solve your problem:

```
for anchor in soup.select('div.about a'):
    print(anchor.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
After posting I found a solution:

```
username = link.text.split()[0]
```

This seems to get me what I need.